# Select a timespan in a Visual Studio Chart (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, timespan

Is it possible (maybe with third-party tools) to add a two lines in a Chart which can be moved and then get the two Dates (strings) on the edges of these two lines?

Maybe this picture describes the problem better. It should look similiar to this:

[Mockup_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S07qw.png)

Thank you already for your help!

Comment: Could you clarify why you'd want this in Visual Studio? It's quite unclear what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: It has to be either with the tool Chart in Visual Studio or a tool which can be implemented in Visual Studio, because the entire programm, where the Chart is just a tiny part has to be implemented in VS.

Comment: MSChart has a powerful feature that should do the job: Annotations. There is a variety of them, they can be made movable by the user and can even be grouped. The can be anchored to points or to values.

Comment: The Chart has to be implemented for a backup of a database. The user should select a timespan in the chart, which data should be backupped. The chart itself Shows each date with the number of rows added to the database on this date.

Comment: What do you mean by "implemented in VS"? Do you mean users have to be in Visual Studio to use it? Or you just mean "I want to write a .NET program and I use Visual Studio to do that"? This sounds very much like a request for third-party library/tool recommendations, to be honest - which are off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I mean: "I want to write a .NET program and I use Visual Studio to do that". Sorry for my articulation. I'm not native english.

Comment: Thank you @TaW for your help. I'll try that.

Comment: Do come back when you run into issues. Annotations can be a little tricky. I have [posted a few solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+annotations) using Annotations..

Comment: BTW: You wrote _'get the two Dates (strings)'_ - This sounds as if your x-values are not really datetimes but strings. I hope they are not as __strings are not valid x-values in a chart!!__ They get discarded although the can be seen in the labels. Do add them as valid datetimes and format the label to show what you want.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to chart.SelectionRangeChanging event to select a timespan and get the correspond datetime.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = new Series();
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

            var d = new DateTime(2020,10,1);

            s.Points.AddXY(d, 30);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(1), 20);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(2), 70);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(3), 90);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(4), 80);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(5), 50);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(6), 60);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(7), 80);
            s.Points.AddXY(d.AddDays(8), 90);

            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Add(s);


            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;

            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2020, 10, 01).AddSeconds(-1);
            DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2020, 10, 08); // or DateTime.Now;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = false;         // red cursor at SelectionEnd
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;     // zoom into SelectedRange
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        }

     
        private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
        {
            double x1 = e.NewSelectionStart;
            double x2 = e.NewSelectionEnd;
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.FromOADate(x1);
            DateTime date2 = DateTime.FromOADate(x2);
            txtStart.Text = date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            txtEnd.Text = date2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect. I added a trackbar and when its value changes, I adjust the selected range in the chart.
I know it's possible to make a trackbar with two slide elements, and so I only have to add some code when the values in the trackbar change.